# What does Im(AB) mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

A and B are matrices. I see this notation used in a lot of online forums, but my textbook doesn't make use of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An $m\times n$ matrix $A$ defines a linear map $T_A:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ given by $T_A(x)=Ax$.

One easily checks that for compatable matrices $A$ and $B$ we have
$$
T_{AB}=T_A\circ T_B
$$
The notation $\DeclareMathOperator{Im}{Im}\Im(AB)$ most likely refers to the *image* of this map. That is,
$$
\Im(AB)=\DeclareMathOperator{image}{image}\image(T_A\circ T_B)=\image(T_{AB})
$$

Answer (score 2):

This is the image set of $AB$.

Comment: The same as the range of $AB$.